# Broadcasting into views of Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, view

I am working with images through numpy. I want to set a chunk of the image to its average color. I am able to do this, but I have to re-index the array, when I would like to use the original view to do this. In other words, I would like to use that 4th line of code, but I'm stuck with the 3rd one.

I have read a few posts about the as_strided function, but it is confusing to me, and I was hoping there might be a simpler solution. So is there a way to slightly modify that last line of code to do what I want?

```py
box = im[x-dx:x+dx, y-dy:y+dy, :]
avg = block(box) #returns a 1D numpy array with 3 values
im[x-dx:x+dx, y-dy:y+dy, :] = avg[None,None,:] #sets box to average color
#box = avg[None,None,:] #does not affect original array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
box = blah
```

just reassigns the `box` variable. The array that the `box` variable previously referred to is unaffected. This is not what you want.

```
box[:] = blah
```

is a slice assignment. It modifies the contents of the array. This is what you want.

Note that slice assignment is dependent on the syntactic form of the statement. The fact that `box` was assigned by `box = im[stuff]` does not make further assignments to `box` slice assignments. This is similar to how if you do

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
b = l[2]
b = 0
```

the assignment to `b` doesn't affect `l`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Gray-scale Images

This will set a chunk of an array to its average (mean) value:

```
im[2:4, 2:4] = im[2:4, 2:4].mean()
```

For example:

```
In [9]: im
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [10]: im[2:4, 2:4] = im[2:4, 2:4].mean()

In [11]: im
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 12],
       [12, 13, 12, 12]])
```

#### Color Images

Suppose that we want to average over each component of color separately:

```
In [22]: im = np.arange(48).reshape((4,4,3))

In [23]: im
Out[23]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]],

       [[36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47]]])

In [24]: im[2:4, 2:4, :] = im[2:4, 2:4, :].mean(axis=0).mean(axis=0)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]

In [25]: im
Out[25]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [37, 38, 39],
        [37, 38, 39]],

       [[36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [37, 38, 39],
        [37, 38, 39]]])
```

Comment: Hmm that definitely looks more Numpy-like than my code. I just used `sp.average(box[...,i])` in a for loop,  appending it to a list which then got converted into an array.